# What is the cause of this error and why am I wrong to think it breaks referential transparency?

Tags: haskell

Sorry to ask this question but it looks to me like it breaks referential transparency.

While exploring a problem and breaking it down (the problem is to get the diagonal elements of a list of lists) I came up with this (correctly working) solution:

```
import Data.List

nums = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]

southwest = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..]
southwest2 = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..] . transpose

my_ans = southwest nums ++ southwest2 nums
```

(N.B. it contains the middle row twice which isn't an issue for my use case)

Now obviously that can easily be refactored. After first trying to write it in a point-free style I figured it would be easier to simply write it non-point-free with these attempts:

```
my_ans2 x = (diagFunc x) ++ (diagFunc . transpose x)
              where diagFunc = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..]

my_ans3 x = concat [(diagFunc x), (diagFunc . transpose x)]
              where diagFunc = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..]
```

Now neither of these compiles and works which I find confusing as it seems to me that that would break referential transparency. Could someone explain why I'm wrong about this and how to correctly write this function (extra points go to writing it in a point-free style as I could not).

For reference the error is here:

```
/home/michael/scripts/temp.hs:14:30:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[[a]]’
                with actual type ‘a0 -> [[a1]]’
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: [[a]]
        (bound at /home/michael/scripts/project_euler/temp.hs:14:9)
      my_ans2 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
        (bound at /home/michael/scripts/project_euler/temp.hs:14:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(diagFunc . transpose x)’
    In the expression: (diagFunc x) ++ (diagFunc . transpose x)
    In an equation for ‘my_ans2’:
        my_ans2 x
          = (diagFunc x) ++ (diagFunc . transpose x)
          where
              diagFunc = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0 .. ]

/home/michael/scripts/temp.hs:14:41:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> [[a1]]’
                with actual type ‘[[a]]’
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: [[a]]
        (bound at /home/michael/scripts/project_euler/temp.hs:14:9)
      my_ans2 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
        (bound at /home/michael/scripts/project_euler/temp.hs:14:1)
    Possible cause: ‘transpose’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘transpose x’
    In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(diagFunc . transpose x)’
```

Again, I'm very sure that I am wrong about this, I just need someone to point out how. :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand the referential transparency bit. Why do you think it would break referential transparency?

Comment: @DavidYoung I thought that I had simply substituted the different parts around without changing anything. What I hadn't noticed was implicit brackets around my statements which I had missed (and which Lee helpfully pointed out). This is going from the definition of referential transparancy where an expression is referentially transparent if it can be replaced with it's value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can fix it with:

```
my_ans2 x = (diagFunc x) ++ (diagFunc . transpose $ x)
              where diagFunc = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..]

my_ans3 x = concat [(diagFunc x), (diagFunc . transpose $ x)]
              where diagFunc = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..]
```

The problem is that `diagFunc . transpose x` is parsed as `diagFunc . (transpose x)`, not `(diagFunc . transpose) x` as you intend.

You can write this in pointfree style using the monoid instance for functions:

```
import Data.Monoid

my_ans2' = diagFunc `mappend` (diagFunc . transpose)
  where diagFunc = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..]
```

The monoid instance for function is available for functions which return monoidal values. Since lists are monoids where `mappend` = `(++)` you can use it here. It is defined as:

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
    mempty _ = mempty
    mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

so `mappend` for functions `f` and `g` apply `f` and `g` to the argument `x` and combines the results using `mappend` for the monoid type `b`. `b` here is a list, so you end up with

```
my_ans2' = (f x) ++ (g x)
```

where `f` is `diagFunc` and `g` is `diagFunc . transpose`.

As @chi points out in the comments you could also use an applicative solution:

```
import Control.Applicative

my_ans2'' = (++) <$> diagFunc <*> (diagFunc . transpose)
  where diagFunc = transpose . zipWith (drop) [0..]
```

which is more general since it does not rely on the return type of the two functions to be monoids.

Comment: Ahhh... brilliant. Thank you. With your explanation now I understand, I knew there was something obvious I was missing.

Comment: I couldn't ask as well, can you think of a way to write this in a point free style? I feel like it requires a function that distributes one argument to multiple functions does something like that exist? (almost like `tee` in bash).

Comment: @MikeH-R `uncurry (++) . (&&&) diagFunc (diagFunc . transpose)` is what you want. Remember to `import Control.Arrow`.

Comment: @Lee, thank you, you couldn't help with some more explanation, could you? I am familiar with monoid's in an abstract sense but do not fully understand what the monoid instance for functions is (what is the identity, is it `id`? what is the binary operation? how do these combine to distribute the argument to both functions?) Sorry if these are obvious questions.

Comment: @MikeH-R `(++) <$> diagFunc <*> (diagFunc . transpose)` is also a solution, possibly more elegant that using arrows. Lee suggests `mappend`, which is even more elegant in this case, but is less general in that it requires the codomain of the function to be already a monoid (e.g. lists), and that you want to apply `mappend` the the function results after having distributed the arguments.

Comment: @chi Thank you. That does look quite elegant. Could you point me to somewhere I could read about these functions (sorry I'm still getting to grips with haskell). It seems that we're `fmap`-ing `++` over the functions that we are applying sequentially after one another? is that correct? As always, thanks.

Comment: @MikeH-R It takes a while to get used to all these abstract operators. `(&&&)` is from `Control.Arrow` using `((-> a)` as an arrow. Instead `<$>` is just `fmap` with a different nicer symbol, from `Control.Applicative` using functor `((->) a)`. `<*>` is also from there. It is often the case that these operators are not strictly needed (e.g. in your example you can just distribute `x` to both functions), yet they make the code shorter and nicer. Beware that an heavy abuse of such abstract concepts can easily make your code seem obfuscated. Point-free style can quickly become point-less style.